# Can't join a meeting via Zoom 5.10 and update the app to at least 5.11

Tags: windows-7, zoom-meeting

Today when I try to join a meeting via Zoom v5.10.1 (I could do before), a dialog window is appeared with the text **"Update required. Your app version needs to be 5.11.1 or higher to join this meeting. Please update to continue"**.

When I click the button **"Update"**, the next window **"Update Available!"** is appeared with log of versions up to the latest version 5.11.4. When I click **"Update"**, the downloading process is started and completed and then the button **"Install"** is appeared. When I click the **"Install"**, both windows of Zoom are disappeared for a while.

After a while the very first Zoom window with the buttons **"Join"** and **"Sign In"** is appeared again, I see the version is still 5.10 and if I try to join a meeting, everything is repeated.

How to resolve the issue?

I still use Windows 7 Home Premium

---

**UPDATE #1**

It's interesting that I can successfully join a personal room of another person, but can't join the meeting I mentioned above. So may this requirement of minimum 5.11.1 version be a setting of the meeting I can't join to?

---

**UPDATE #2**

I've found the page at Zoom website which says that their app still supports Windows 7

Also I've found the page by the link https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360061238351-Requiring-users-to-update-Zoom which describes where and how the admin of the meeting can specify the minimum required version of the app of the users. And I shared the link with the admin, but he said that he can't find the menu item "Account settings" under the "Account Management" in the navigation panel of the account as mentioned at the page

Comment: What's wrong in the question?

Comment: So you did an update, it looks like it was successful and Zoom is functional. Did you try to join a meeting yet?

Comment: When I try, everything is repeated

Comment: Did you try to uninstall it and download and reinstall the latest version from [here](https://zoom.us/download)?  Apart from that: **Do not use Windows 7 anymore, it hasn't got any security updates since over 2 1/2 years and will be extremely easy to infect, even by "scriptkiddie" malware** Your license and key will usually also work on Windows 10, there is no need to keep using heavily outdated and unsafe software!

Comment: When I uninstall Zoom and re-install the latest version, I get the error "Installation Failed: Error Code 10003"

Comment: Did you use a search engine of your choice and feed it with the error you got, to be precise with `Zoom Error Code 10003`. The first possible solution is a [support article from Zoom](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/6621090983949-Zoom-error-code-10003). If that doesn't work try another suggestion from the search results.

Comment: @mashuptwice yes, I read the information about the error 10003 early (as this error occurs not at the first time) and tried the solutions that are recommended, but nothing helped

Answer (score 1):

It might be that Zoom no longer supports Windows 7. In that case, move to a newer operating system. If you cannot upgrade your PC to Windows 10, then you might consider another OS, such as Linux.

You can run a Linux version such as Ubuntu [*directly from a USB flash drive,*](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/) without installing it, to test if you like it. [To add Zoom](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/204206269-Installing-or-updating-Zoom-on-Linux#h_75e1dc24-8db1-4b89-8db9-eb049f9b7987) (for the test session only, unless you make a persistent Ubuntu USB), open terminal and enter the following line:

`sudo apt install ./zoom_amd64.deb`

If that works well for you, then you can permanently install Ubuntu, either dual-booting with Windows, or by itself, and then install Zoom permanently, as above.